# Using resize function from minimum number of resizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, resize

I have a website, which has some functions that are related to tablet view and some that are related to phone view - mostly menu configuration.
To overcome the need to refresh the website every time the device is changing it's orientation, i used the resize function to load the relevant functions each time the user resizes his window (aka orientation).

```
function res(){
var reswidth = $(window).width();
//REMOVING SOME MENU STYLES
$('.logo').removeClass('logoTop');
$('.menuList').removeClass('ulTop');
$('.menuList').removeClass('openMenu');
$('.menuList').removeClass('openMenu0');
$('.logo').unbind();
$('.menu-item').unbind();
$('.menuList').unbind();
$('.icon-menu').unbind();
$('.menuListItem').unbind();
$('.menu').unbind();
$('.info').unbind();
//DETECTING WHICH DEVICE IS IT.
if (reswidth > 1000) {
    slideshow();
    tablet();
    if (reswidth > 1600) {
        audio();
    }
}
else {
    phone();
    $('.menu').localScroll();   
}
}

$(window).ready(res).resize(res);
```

The problem with this method is that actually the mobile browsers are resizing all the time! every time the user scrolls (in any direction) the browser is changing it's size (menu bars, tab bars and address bar) which leads to removing and recalling the phone() function over and over again.

I'm looking for a way to enable the resize function ONLY if the user has passed a specific amount of pixels/resizes numbers.. so changing 100px won't count as a resize.

Is that possible with jQuery?
live example can be seen at [boazkerengil.com/zoubisou](http://boazkerengil.com/zoubisou)

Comment: Why don't you consider using css3 media query? seeing that you're taking care of mobile, old browsers are not your concerns I guess?

Comment: I am using media queries. but there are stuff I can't do with CSS, like changing the menu buttons attributes and so on. The website is pretty much working on old browsers, the problem is with mobile and it's never ending resizing, which triggers the resize functions all the time :(

Comment: If you need to do this much when resizing, your site is not very well constructed. However, if its only orientation your are looking for you could do `if(window.innerwidth > window.innerheight)` to check if its landscape, or opposite if its portrait and only switch on those occasions. Otherwise you'll have to do a lot more work figuring this out in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by moving the .removeClass functions to the if statements - this results the expected behaviour that only when the user changes the device it removes the unnecessary classes.

```
function res(){
var reswidth = $(window).width();
$('.logo').unbind();
$('.menu-item').unbind();
$('.menuList').unbind();
$('.icon-menu').unbind();
$('.menuListItem').unbind();
$('.menu').unbind();
$('.info').unbind();
if (reswidth > 1000) {
    $('.logo').removeClass('logoTop');
    $('.menuList').removeClass('ulTop');
    $('.menuList').removeClass('openMenu');
    $('.menuList').removeClass('openMenu0');
    slideshow();
    tablet();
    if (reswidth > 1600) {
        audio();
    }
}
else {
    phone();
    $('.menu').localScroll();   
}
}
```

Comment: Seriously, _media queries_.

Comment: Check the website at boazkerengil.com/zoubisou  the whole layout changes and I don't need the localscroll on the larger screen, that's why it's a combination of media queries and JS.

Comment: Maybe, but you could survive with adding just one class to your body when going mobile and handling the rest in css. only adding a class to the menu when you tap the 'tap me' and that class should only work in mobile. Just to say, try looking at your site _without_ javascript, as it should be accessible without it.